Multiple Blazor clients on .NET 8
I'm stuck when migrating multiple Blazor Wasm apps to .NET 8 (Blazor web app). On .NET 6, my solution worked properly, if anybody has the same issue or already resolved it please give me some ideas or keywords to resolve this in .NET 8. Thank you so much!
This is my repo that worked fine on .NET 6:
https://github.com/skillcrushbinguyen/MultipleBlazorApps

Hi @Bi Nguyễn, what you shared is the project for .NET 8. What you have done for migration? What's the problem you meet? Pls share enough details.
